# oxford dictionary database for NLP

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am using NLP for sentiment analysis ,so I need to determine the type of speech , can any one help me where can I download dataset/database  for oxford dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Oxford dictionary is not freely available.

As an alternative,

you can download The Gutenberg Project hosts [Webster's Unabridged English Dictionary](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29765) plus many other public domain literary works.

- [DictionaryDatabase](https://github.com/eddydn/DictionaryDatabase) - Project converter The Online Text Plain English Dictionary (OPTED) to SQLite database and JSON